# Unable to identify the <p> tag in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am working on XSLT. I was unable to find xslt. I have tried.

Source:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <body>
<selectedComp>bodyParagraphText</selectedComp>
<value>
  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">abd</p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> </p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">afh</p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> </p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">AAA</p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> </p>


  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">ZZZ</p>
</value>
</body>
```

XSLT written:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:widget="aaa">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="body/value/p">
       <xsl:element name= "widget:bodyParagraphText">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:template>


       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i am not getting any thing. I am getting empty xml at the end.

But output required:

```
   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text>abd</text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>

   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text> </text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>

   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text>afh</text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>

   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text> </text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>

   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text>AAA</text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>

   <widget:bodyParagraphText>
   <text> </text>
   </widget:bodyParagraphText>
```

Can any one suggest how it can be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` element has a namespace of `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, which you need to include in your XPath expression:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:widget="aaa"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="body/value/xhtml:p">
            <widget:bodyParagraphText>
                <text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </text>
            </widget:bodyParagraphText>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the addition of the `xmlns:xhtml` attribute on the root tag, as well as the `xhtml:` prefix in the XPath expression.